# OSX El Capitan: How to Use Full Screen Applications with Multiple Monitors

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, osx-el-capitan

I have an external monitor and an iMac running OSX El Capitan. When I open a game and (in the game options) go full screen the monitor that has another application open (not in full screen) goes black.

I would like to enable full screen mode in one monitor's application and have the other monitor's screen not go black. Is this possible; if so how?

Below are a list of things I have tried and failed to get working.

I have enabled the following option in my System Preferences, [suggested on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/2kkwb9/yosemite_multi_monitor_fullscreen_mode_all_other/).

```
System Preferences → Mission Control → Displays have separate spaces
```

The displays are setup like so.

[image: Display setup]

The Mission Control is set up like so.

[image: Mission Control setup]

Comment: Did you reboot yet? The reddit answer should be correct.

Comment: I logged out, should I reboot too?

Comment: Can but try....

Comment: I'm at work now, but I'll try when I get home and update then.

Comment: @Tetsujin No that didn't work.

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. Vimeo does video full screen without trying to take over both monitors but Tidal app always does.

Comment: @enijar Restarting my Mac Pro Silver Tower (not just login/logout) solved the issue. It's really nice not to have full screen videos from YouTube and Tidal taking over both of my huge monitors. Thank you! I've voted you up.

Caveat: you can't use the second monitor for anything else of course until you close full screen. I.e. app and window switching doesn't work on the second monitor.